# Angular why $event object changes the property

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following html:

```html
<!-- See click event -->
<div *ngFor="let tabComp of tabCompArr" (click)="selectTab(tabComp)">
    {{ tabComp.title }}
</div>
```

And in component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.tabCompArr = [...]
}

selectTab( selectedTab ) {
    // this changes tabCompArr property. WHY?
    selectedTab.active = true;
}
```

Why setting `selectedTab.active` to true, changes the `tabCompArr` property? Isn't the `selectedTab` a local variable?

Comment: Yes, `selectedTab` is a local variable, but it **references** a different variable, so changes to the local variable will modify the reference also. If you don't want this behavior, you need to directly pass the value of the reference.

Comment: I would say because you are passing a portion of the original variable tabCompArr as written "let tabComp of tabCompArr". So your selectTab(tabComp) changes the original one by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to undestand what is [call-by-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). This is how parameters are passed to a function in JavaScript.

Consider the following example:

```
var obj = { foo: 1 };

function selectTab( obj) {
   obj.foo = 2;
}


selectTab(obj);

obj.foo // prints 2
```

The same will happen if you take any object from array and pass it to a function.

```
var arr = [{ foo: 1 }];

function selectTab( obj) {
   obj.foo = 2;
}

selectTab(arr[0]);

arr // prints [{foo: 2}]
```

Array keeps reference to that object which we pass by sharing to function where the `foo` property has changed.

See also:

- [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)
- https://blog.bitsrc.io/master-javascript-call-by-sharing-parameter-passing-7049d65163ed

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have the same array `tabCompArr` at html and your typescript file. As array is reference  type, so changing an item of array will change an item of an array.

For example:

```
let array = [{a: true, q: 1}, {b: false, r: 2}, ];
let item = array[0];
item.a = false;

console.log(array);
```

UPDATE:

You can create another variable to avoid such behavior:

```
chosenTab: any;

selectTab( selectedTab ) {
    // this changes tabCompArr property. WHY?
    this.chosenTab.active = true;
}
```

Comment: So, I pass the value to the function's argument. The argument should have a local variable, isn't it? I don't know what I missing, maybe a feature of javascript!

Comment: So, you mean I pass it by reference, not value? How can I pass the value? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, modify your function so that it takes the value you want. IE `selectTab(tabComp.active)`. Objects and arrays are simply references to their child values.

Answer (score -2):

It's happen due to Two way biding functionality of Angular.
In Two way binding if variable created in .ts file and if you update it from UI side then it automatically update to original object .

Thanks,

Comment: It has nothing to do with two-way binding and Angular itself

Comment: This has nothing to do with two way binding. OP's problem is he doesn't understand how JavaScript handles references to values.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make any sense with Angular two-way data binding.

Comment: @VahidNajafi It's definitely happen due to two way binding functionality.You don't need to update that value to array, if you update that to that parameter it's directly affect to that array. just console log that array after you update that parameter , you will find updated array.

Comment: There is no form here, so "two-way data binding" doesn't make any sense. Please check the accepted answer.